# Cloudflare GraphQL Analytic API does not have access to the path

Tags: cloudflare

When I tried query this query

```
query ($zoneID: String!) {
  viewer {
    zones(filter: {zoneTag: $zoneID}) {
      httpRequestsAdaptiveGroups(filter: {date_gt: "2022-05-29"}, limit: 100) {
        count
        dimensions {
          requestSource
        }
        sum {
          visits
          edgeResponseBytes
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and it gave me this error

```json
{
  "data": null,
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "zone '0ab45c20ea56c46d2db5999b19221234' does not have access to the path",
      "path": [
        "viewer",
        "zones",
        "0",
        "httpRequestsAdaptiveGroups"
      ],
      "extensions": {
        "code": "authz",
        "timestamp": "2022-06-29T06:14:55.82422442Z"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

How to have access to viewing httpRequestsAdaptiveGroups, do I have to upgrade the project plan because right now it is currently on **free-tier**

What I've tried so far was giving all the zone readable-permission and it still happen

[image]